# replace Jquery UI mouseover event with click event

Tags: jquery-ui

http://klaussongs.com/
I have this table on my site that when you hover over the tabs, it changes it. But I want to make it so it works on click I tried defining that on my code by saying:

```
$("#tabs").tabs();
```

But it is not overriding the jquery UI CDNed file main event which is mouseover. I can see on console under eventlistener that it has a mouseover listener attached to it, how do I override that to work on click. I also tried this, but it didn't work:

```
      $("#tabs").tabs({
        event: "click"
      });
```

Comment: The link you have is for a site with a mess of libraries and code. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The files related to this code is inside a wp-content -> plugins -> builder -> assets. This is a wordpress plugin I made

Comment: When asking a question, people will be better able to provide help if you provide code that they can easily understand and use to reproduce the problem. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask